# Android WebView Cookie issue

Tags: php, android, mysql, cookies, webview

I am trying to build a voting system using php-cookies on a Android Webview, so my php script inside webview checks if the cookie is set, if its not, new cookie will be set and vote will be incremented by 1 in mysql db, and the user who voted previously cant vote again for the same pic.

When I try the voting system on any browser, like chrome on phone,computer. It works great. But when I try it on android webview. The cookie is not properly managed and there seems to be a bug, that I can vote multiple times for a single pic. However, on Android L webview, this is working perfect. Kitkat and below flavours having this issue with cookies, the cookie is not properly managed.

How can this problem be solved? 
And I know that using cookies is not a great idea, however want a solution for this.

Below is my java class for webview

```
public class Review extends Activity {
    WebView mWeb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_review);
        mWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWeb);
        mWeb.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        mWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        mWeb.loadUrl("http://somewebsite.com/review.php");
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that it might be because you aren't using some deprecated methods (sort of counter-intuitive) that are required for cookies to work prior to Lollipop. On Lollipop and beyond, the **CookieManager** singleton works fine by itself, however, prior to Lollipop it also required the use of an additional static method from **CookieSyncManager**. The code below works for me on all Android versions when setting the cookies on a WebView.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
}
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
```

This initializes the CookieSyncManager and allows the cookies to properly work prior to Lollipop. Let me know if this works or not.